# SQL: need to query single column with several transaction types and output in tabular format

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query a single table that contains records for several different types of transactions:
[image: table]

and produce output in tabular format (without using an Excel pivot table, of course):
[image]

Is there a better way to do this than by JOINing several subqueries? And if there is no better way, how should I go about the order of the JOINs?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select yyyymm,
       sum(case when type = 'CNFF Iny' then amount end) as cnff_iny,
       sum(case when type = 'CNFF Ret' then amount end) as cnff_ret,
       . . .   -- and so on for all the values
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```